# How to set the listview trailing padding

Tags: flutter, android-listview

I am using listview.builder to show the api data, i want to set the text padding, here is the output

[image]

i want to set the approved and not approved text after the date.

here is my code

```
ListTile(
       leading:  CircleAvatar(
       radius: 25,
       backgroundColor:snapshot.data[index].type=="Sick"?Color(int.parse(annualboxcolor)):Color(int.parse(maternityboxcolor)),
       child: Container(
       padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
       child:Column(children: <Widget>[
       Text(snapshot.data[index].noofdays.toString(),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color:Colors.white),),  
       Text(int.parse(snapshot.data[index].noofdays)>1?"Days":"Day",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0,color:Colors.white),)
       ]
                            
     ),
     )),
    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].type),
    subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].fromdate+" To "+snapshot.data[index].todate),
    trailing: Text(snapshot.data[index].Status=="ON"?"Approved":"Not Approved"),),
Container(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(80, 55, 0, 0),
                          child:Text(snapshot.data[index].Status=="ON"?"Approved":"Not Approved",
                            style: TextStyle(color:snapshot.data[index].Status=="ON"?Colors.green:Colors.red ),),),
```

i used container and set its padding but i want to do this in `listtile`

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53539523/flutter-how-to-use-listtile-threeline/53539803

Comment: @PeterKoltai i used that, but it requires padding, it disturb the alignment of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead using `trailing`, set `isThreeLine` to `true`, that makes the `ListTile` to display 3 lines of text instead of 2. After that, make `subtitle` a two line string with the data and the approved state, something like this:

```
ListTile(
    // your existing code
    isThreeLine: true,
    // concatenate you strings, this is just an example,
    // mind the `\n`, it makes new line
    subtitle: Text("2021-02-02 To 2021-03-03\nNot Approved"),
    // don't use trailing
    // trailing: 
)
```

If you need different styling, there is another way, using a `Column` in `subtitle`, and add separate `Text` widgets:

```
ListTile(
    // ...
    isThreeLine: true,
    subtitle: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
            Text("2021-02-02 To 2021-03-03",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
            Text("Not Approved", 
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red))
        ],
    )
)
```

Comment: thannks it works, but i want to change the color which is in new line, not both values, do u know how to do this?

Comment: You are welcome, added another solution to my answer which allows different styling. You can also try without `isThreeLine`, check how it fits, but I would go with it just to be safe on different phones.

Comment: thannkss once again, it works perfectly, and u mean ```isThreeLine``` will be safe for different phones?

Comment: `isThreeLine` makes the `ListTile` a little higher, assuming that it will hold three lines of text. Try to comment it out and you will see the difference. It is safe for different phones, but you can try without it and test it.

Comment: yes, i did that, ```ListTile``` height gets smaller than before.

Comment: So it is up to you whether you use it or not, `ListTile` will automatically grow in height if the content is higher. In my opinion, if there is a config like this for 3 lines, it is reasonable to set it if you know you will have 3 lines :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope it's helpful to you use isThreeLine instead of trailing

```
ListTile( 
    leading: CircleAvtar(
           child:Text('Sick'),
     ),
      title: Text('Sick'),
      subtitle:Text('Your Date\n Approved'),
     isThreeLine:true,
),
```